# Cannot remove element from foreach if list row contains a textField in SwiftUI

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I have read several solutions to this issue which I believe I am doing correctly based on suggestions but this simple code still crashes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnItem : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items : [AnItem] = [AnItem(text: "A"), AnItem(text: "B"), AnItem(text: "C")]
    var body: some View {
        List () {
            ForEach (0 ..< items.count) {
                        index in
                TextField("test", text: $items[index].text)
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        }
    }
    private func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        self.items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

Anybody have an idea for a workaround, or maybe I'm just doing this wrong.  The crash says

```
Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
```

As others have stated, just a Text widget works fine. This appears to be induced by using TextField.

Comment: You need to use textfield? or can i change it to a better solution for you?

Comment: No it needs to be a TextField.  I know it works fine with Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. Using `id:\.id` to identity the items and then extract the TextField to another view

```
struct AnItem : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items : [AnItem] = [AnItem(text: "A"), AnItem(text: "B"), AnItem(text: "C")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                CustomTextField(item: item)
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        }
    }
    private func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }

}

struct CustomTextField : View {
    @State var item : AnItem
    
    var body : some View {
        TextField("Test", text: $item.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: That works.  Thank you. I'm not clear if this is how SwiftUI is supposed to work or if this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks @davidev But why we need to extract TextField() in a custom View?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this:

1. First lets make `AnItem` conform to `Hashable` protocol.

   ```
   struct AnItem : Identifiable, Hashable {
   let id = UUID()
   var text: String
   }
   ```
2. Now let's change your `Foreach` and `List` a little bit:

   ```
   List {
       ForEach (items, id: \.self) { item in
           Text("\(item.text)")
       }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
   }
   ```

Voila! everything is working perfectly now!

[image: results]

Comment: OP uses TextField, not Text. It's a difference

Comment: Correct, the issue is induced with TextField which I need in my application.